# Unable to read data from excel in selenium POM pattern

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

I am keeping my data in excel file and read the data from there, because of avoid hard code..

**Page**

```
public void fielding(String field,String dist,String velo,String diff) {
  enterFielding.sendKeys(field);
  saveButton.click();
  textDistance.sendKeys(dist);
  dropDown.click();
  driver.findElement(By.name(velo)).click();
  textDifficulty.sendKeys(diff);
  buttonUpdate.click();
}

public void popOuttop2(String field,String dist,String velo,String diff) {
 //BH
 buttonB.click();
 buttonH.click();
 popOutButton.click();
 fielding(field,dist,velo,diff);
 buttonUpdate.click();
}
```

**Steps**

```
public class BaseBallEventSteps {

    WebDriver driver;
    BaseBallOutEvents baseOut;
    public BaseBallEventSteps() {
        baseOut = new BaseBallOutEvents(driver);
        baseOut=  PageFactory.initElements(DriverManager.driver, BaseBallOutEvents.class);
    }

    public void firstInningTopOut1(String field,String dist,String velo,String diff) throws InterruptedException 
    {
        baseOut.strikeOuttop1();
        baseOut.popOuttop2(field, dist, velo, diff);
        baseOut.strikeOutTop3();
    }
}
```

**Main method**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException {


 DriverManager manager=new DriverManager();

 BaseBallEventSteps bs=new BaseBallEventSteps();

 File f= new File("Player_names.xlsx");
 FileInputStream fs= new FileInputStream(f);
 XSSFWorkbook wb= new XSSFWorkbook(fs); 
 XSSFSheet bb_players=  wb.getSheet("Sheet2");
 int rowcount= bb_players.getLastRowNum();

 String field =  bb_players.getRow(1).getCell(1).getStringCellValue();
 String dist= bb_players.getRow(1).getCell(2).getStringCellValue();
 String velo=bb_players.getRow(1).getCell(3).getStringCellValue();
 String diff=bb_players.getRow(1).getCell(4).getStringCellValue();

 bs.firstInningTopOut1(field,dist,velo,diff);
}
```

[image]

I want to know that I am doing correct or not ?
My data from excel is not reading in the main class...
Error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get a text value from a numeric cell
```

every time that i need to write the same `String field =  bb_players.getRow(1).getCell(1).toString();`  to read the value from each cell.. but the length of the code should be more and is that every one following ?

Anybody please review my code , that i am doing correct or not, i can go further ?

Comment: For what it's worth, this is one reason I keep my locators inside the page object classes themselves - they are the only classes that need to know the locators, why add another layer of complexity in having to read in tables from other files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me the problem seems to be in the type of the values you are trying to use. The cell probably contains a number type and you are expecting a String in your code.
I would suggest one of the following:

- change the excel cell's type to text
- instead of getStringCellValue() try getIntegerCellValue() or a similar method
- use the toString() method

Comment: thanks for the support, that toString works fine for me... but let me know that I am doing correct or not..any changes should  I need 
 for my code improvement or i can go further ?

Comment: you're welcome :) you know, code improvement depends on the size and duration of the project. If this is just a random homework or a two weeks project, nobody cares so much about the code quality. But if you'll working on this for 2 years, I suggest to be as modular as you can, to separate many things in wrapping classes. Good luck, man!